# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined with cypress

Tags: cypress

I am running some tests that are just grabbing inputs and filling them in with data and there are a lot.

I have multiple tests like the code below:

```
cy.get('input').eq(0)
.type('4')
.type('{selectall}')
.type('500000')
.type('{backspace}')
```

And, I keep getting this error:
[image]
Also the amount for that error keeps increasing very rapidly in the console!

Anyone know why this is happening in Cypress?

Comment: Did you check if this error arises from your application?

Comment: It has probably to do something with an API-call, but the developer-tools of your browser should be able to help you with that. The code itself doesn't have an issue on my local machine.